# Function to build table columns and relationships in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to put together a function to build tables and their relationships using SQLAlchemy. The problem is that I am working with tables with many columns and many foreign keys. Some of the relationships are many-to-one, but some others are many-to-many. Since there are many parties interested in the outcome of the database, there will be for sure additional columns added in the future. Hence, being able to build tables from a function is desirable. This is what I have after a couple of days looking around:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey, MetaData, Table, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


db = "alchemy_database_test.db"
db_memory = 'sqlite:///' + db
engine = create_engine(db_memory)

Base = declarative_base()
post_meta = MetaData(bind=engine)

#Example of names to build tables and columns
col_names = ['productID', 'productShortName', 'productName','quantity']
col_types = [Integer, String, String, Integer]
primary_key_flags = [True, False, False, False]
nullable_flags = [False, False, False, False]

# Lists to build relationship statements
## relationship name
name_of_target = ['platforms','regions','references', 'protocols']
# name of the target table containing the foreign ID to link
name_of_target_table = ['platform','region','reference','protocol']

# Since I am using a single list of foreign keys, and many-to-one has a different 
# syntax compared to many-to-many relationships (or so I think), I'm building two
# lists and filling in with None to make them the same size and iterate 
# simultaneously through both

## for many to one relationships
name_of_target_column = ['platformID','regionID',None,None]
## for many to many relationships
name_of_column_m2m = [None,None,'referenceID','protocolID']

def create_sqltable(post_meta,name,col_names,col_types,primary_key_flags,
   link_tos=[], link_to_table=[], link_to=[], many_to_many=[]):

   test = Table(name, post_meta,

               #here i'm creating the columns and assigning primary key
               #and auto-increment, if needed. This works well.

               *(Column(c_names, c_types,
                       primary_key=primary_key_flag,
                       autoincrement=primary_key_flags,
                       nullable=nullable_flag)
               for c_names,
                   c_types,
                   primary_key_flag,
                   nullable_flag in zip(col_names,
                                           col_types,
                                           primary_key_flags,
                                           nullable_flags)),

               #I'm trying to do the same with the relationship statement
               # building a statement for each foreign key by assigning
               # the name of the relationship, the target table, and 
               # either a 'backref' or a 'secondary' argument depending 
               # if it is a maney-to-one or a many-to-many relationship

               *(relationship(lk_tos, #name of the relationship
                       lk_to_table, #name of the target table
                       secondary=mny_to_mny, #name of the column in the target
                                             # table (many2many relationship)
                       backref=lk_to_col, #name of the column in the target 
                                          # table (many2one relationship)
                       cascade="all,delete")
               for lk_tos, # name of relationship
                   lk_to_table, # name of target table
                   lk_to_col, # name of column in target table (many2one)
                   mny_to_mny in zip(link_tos,
                                           link_to_table,
                                           link_to,
                                           many_to_many))) # column in target table(many2many)
   test.create()

#calling the function with the lists declared earlier
create_sqltable(post_meta,'table_name',col_names, col_types, primary_key_flags,
       name_of_target, name_of_target_table, name_of_target_column, name_of_column_m2m)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/OneDrive - 3M/Projects/Searchable database/Code/Relational-Database/database_wd_v3.py in 
      59     ['table1','table2','customer','lamp','crystals'],
      60     ['table1ID','table2ID','customerID',None,None],
----> 61     [None,None,None,'lampID','crystalID'])

~/OneDrive - 3M/Projects/Searchable database/Code/Relational-Database/database_wd_v3.py in create_sqltable(post_meta, name, col_names, col_types, primary_key_flags, link_tos, link_to_table, link_to, many_to_many)
     51                                             link_to_table,
     52                                             link_to,
---> 53                                             many_to_many)))
     54     test.create()

~/OneDrive - 3M/Projects/Searchable database/Code/Relational-Database/database_wd_v3.py in (.0)
     48                     lk_to_table,
     49                     lk_to_col,
---> 50                     mny_to_mny in zip(link_tos,
     51                                             link_to_table,
     52                                             link_to,

TypeError: relationship() got multiple values for argument 'secondary'
```

Since this is my first attempt at SQLite and SQLAlchemy, I am guessing this is the least of my problems. But, I have not been able to correct this issue after eliminating values passes or even just typing a string directly (i.e. secondary = 'referenceID').

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The problem comes from the way you call `relationship()`. You do indeed pass the argument `secondary` twice. So the error is exactly what you see in the traceback. However, your abbreviated and non-semantic variable names and missing code-comments make it really tough to provide an alswer without breaking to overall logic. It is pretty convoluted. If you clean it up I will have another shot at it.

Comment: @exhuma Thanks for taking a look. I appreciate your time. I added some comments to explain my variables. Please let me know if that makes a bit more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue in the arguments to [relationship()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship). When you look at the documentation, you will see that the first argument is the target table, and the second is the secondary table for many-to-many relationships. The important part of the function signature is:

```
def sqlalchemy.orm.relationship(argument, secondary=None, ...
```

In your code you call it like this:

```
relationship(lk_tos, #name of the relationship
                       lk_to_table, #name of the target table
                       secondary=mny_to_mny, #name of the column in the target
                                             # table (many2many relationship)
                       backref=lk_to_col, #name of the column in the target 
                                          # table (many2one relationship)
                       cascade="all,delete")
```

the key point here is that you pass two positional arguments (`lk_tos` and `lk_to_table`) which, according to the SQLAlchemy definition, will go into `argument` and `secondary` respectively. But then you pass an additional keyword argument as `secondary=mny_to_mny`. That means that `secondary` gets the value `lk_to_table` and also `mny_to_mny`. This explains the error you see.

I suggest splitting the many-to-many relationships away from the one-to-many relationship. That should give you more flexibility to call the function properly.

Unfortunately I am unable to untangle your code in my mind to give you a proper suggestion of new code.